# InvalidOperationException when trying to insert a string larger than 4000 chars into SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql, string, sql-server-ce, truncate

The following is my logic (which adds a row of data to the database). This logic works, but when I have a string length larger than 4000 characters for `log.Value.Message`, it fails on `rs.Insert`. Why is that? How can I get around this? I tried searching the web but I couldn't find anything on this. The connection string will look something like this:

```
Data Source=C:\\File.sdf;Max Database Size=4000;Password=password;
```

Code:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
SqlCeResultSet rs;
SqlCeUpdatableRecord rec;

conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "LogRecords";  // Table name.
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable);
rec = rs.CreateRecord();

foreach (KeyValuePair<UInt64,LogRecord> log in v)
{
    rec.SetGuid(0, log.Value.ID);
    rec.SetSqlString(4, log.Value.Message);
    rs.Insert(rec);
}
```

This is the exception I see:

> String truncation: max=4000, len=6850, value='[MY HUGE STRING FULL OF THE ENTIRE LOREM IPSUM TEXT, A LENGTH OF 6850]'.

This is how I create my database:

```
SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(ConnectionString);
engine.CreateDatabase();
```

Comment: @DJKRAZE: SQL Server **CE** doesn't have `varchar(max)` - you need to use `text` (for non-Unicode) or `ntext` for Unicode strings

Comment: I just realized that he's using Sql Server CE

Comment: @marc_s - Hey, thanks guys. How would I add that in on the creation of the database?

Comment: How do you create your table?

Comment: I'm using DbSet on a class of log records, where I define a [Key] Guid theGuid, string message, etc.

Comment: Is it a matter of setting the StringLength property on this class that it's creating the DB from?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx

Comment: figured it out, needed to set the typename, ie:

[Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
public string Body { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, needed to set the typename, ie: [Column(TypeName = "ntext")] public string Body { get; set; }